# How to create dynamic color list for charts

Tags: php, api, charts, logic, pie-chart

How to create dynamic color list for charts

Basically i have a different value in my database or each values contain each percentage and i need to show this percentages in pie chart with different colors ....

This is the example code of pie chart in static way

```
<color value="#99CDFB"/>
<color value="#3366FB"/>
<color value="#0000FA"/>
<color value="#F8CC00"/>
<color value="#F89900"/>
<color value="#F76600"/>
```

but i need dynamic way using PHP ( **for loop / foreach loop**) like this

```
$color = "";
foreach($data as $data){
   echo '<color value=".$color."/>';
}
```

and i don't know to create dynamic color list also see the screenshot for verification
[image]

Comment: Do you want a random string of colors too?

Comment: but how and help are definitely appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For random string of colors, here:

```
function randColor( $numColors ) {
    $chars = "ABCDEF0123456789";   
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    $str = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < $numColors; $i++ ) {
        for( $j = 0; $j < 6; $j++ ) {
            $str[$i] .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Then, in your function, use `$colors = randColor( 6 );` to create a total of 6 different colors. After that, here's your output color method.

```
foreach( $colors as $codeColor ) {
    echo "<color value=\"#{$codeColor}\" />\n";
}
```

Comment: i love your code thanx for sharing your experience with me also see this link i have tested http://codepad.org/Awq16Wnu

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to use an aproach using [dechex()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.dechex.php) function. First you have to prepare three 0-255 random numbers, convert them to hex and join to make a string. Then you can also use the calculated numbers to assign text color: black for light colors or white for darker, like:

```
    if( ($r + $g + $b) / 3 > 126)
        $textcolor="#000000";
    else
        $textcolor="#FFFFFF";
```

Another idea is to generate shaded random colors. You may first generate three random numbers from 0 to let say 40 - for the first color, then, second color will be from 40 to 80, and so on...